# Networkx display eigenvector centrality values next to nodes

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I have a circular layout networkx weighted graph. I was wondering if, after computing the eigenvector centrality values, if there were a way to display the values **on the graph** **next to its respective node**?

I'm using the [eigenvector centrality numpy function](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.eigenvector_centrality_numpy.html#networkx.algorithms.centrality.eigenvector_centrality_numpy):

```
centrality = nx.eigenvector_centrality_numpy(G)

print([f"{node} {centrality[node]:0.3f}" for node in centrality])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can set the result of `nx.eigenvector_centrality_numpy` as node labels for `nx.draw` function, because `nx.eigenvector_centrality_numpy` returns a dict like `{node: value}` for each node in the graph, which is equal to the format `nx.draw` labels uses:

```
import networkx as nx

# Create a random graph
G = nx.gnp_random_graph(20, 0.2)

# Calculate centrality
centrality = nx.eigenvector_centrality_numpy(G)

# Create labels dict with fixed digit format
labels = {
    node: '{:.3f}'.format(centrality[node])
    for node in centrality
}

# Draw the graph with labels
nx.draw(
    G,
    with_labels=True,
    labels=labels,
    node_color='#FF0000'
)
```

[image]